# What is the proper way to use include with or without brackets in php

Tags: php, include, require

I already know how to use `include`, `require` and even `require_once`. What I have always practiced is this:

for example `include 'sample.php';` or `require_once 'classes/DB.php';`

But in some ways I often see in some forums and tutorials and even here that they are using it like this - `include ('sample.php');` and `require_once ('classes/DB.php');`.

I know that any of this will work, but I just want to know what would you recommend maybe as a good practice? XD and if it's already been asked here please show me the link because I can't find it.

Comment: @Patrick: link is something different than the question.

Comment: @Patrick the link that you shared is not relative to the question.

Comment: @Patrick, Thanks but like what i have said i already know how to use it i just want some thoughts and advice.

Comment: `()` is optional. Always use `'somefile.php'` instead of `()` because `require/include` not a function they are language construct.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `include 'sample.php';` or `require_once 'classes/DB.php';`  is a preferred way.

> Is preferred, it will prevent your peers from giving you a hard time and a trivial conversation about what require really is.

[**Reference**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php#75875).

**Side Notes:**

*1.* `require/include` not a function they are language construct same as `echo`. *Credits:* @Rahil comment.

*2.* Also it will save time of pressing two keystroke `(` & `)` for a *lazy developers* like us :p

Comment: lol! Thanks for the advice, but i think the best answer is your side note, because i'm a lazy developer :D. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Best comment "lazy developers" +1 (deserved +100)

Answer (score 10):

`include` and the rest are not *functions*, they do not need the parentheses. Parentheses are also used for grouping, for example `1 + (2 * 3)`. You can basically add as many parentheses around any expression as you want; `1 + (2 * 3)` is equivalent to `(1 + (2 * 3))` is equivalent to `1 + ((2 * 3))` is equivalent to `((1) + (((2) * (3))))`.

So all `include ('file.php')` is doing is add unnecessary grouping parentheses around the expression `'file.php'`. You may as well write `include (((('file.php'))))`, it has exactly the same effect, which is none. It's usually only done by people who do not understand this fact and believe the parentheses to be necessary "like with other functions", or maybe who like the style.

Comment: +1  @deceze In my opinion this is the best answer as it actually explains the (un)use(fullness) of the parentheses `()` .  A follow up question: what if I want to include two files at once, what would the correct way(s) of that be?

Comment: @Sam `require_once 'file1.php'; require_once 'file2.php';`

Comment: @deceze Thanks and +1! So, there is no shorter way like `include 'file1.php' . 'file2.php'`, (tried didn't work out) so I *must* write the `include` word twice separated with `;`?

Comment: @Sam No, there is not.