# PHP-Why dont work relative path for me by (../) But work with (./)?

Tags: php, filepath, wampserver, relative-path, phpstorm-2017.1

in my php codes when I use require_once() or other relative functions and put relative path, for example (../ref_func.php), doesnt work and has this error:

```
Failed to open stream : No such file or directory
```

**I use**

- **Windows 10**
- **Phpstorm 2017**

and

- **wampserver 3.0.0 for localhost**

**this wamp has PHP 5.6.16 and Apache 2.4.17 active.**

require_once(../ref_func.php) is in clog.php that is in Folder with name checklog_folder.

my directory is same as this:

```
|_www
    |_myweb
      |_scss_folder
         |_content.scss
         |_footer.scss
         |_globals.scss
         |_header.scss
      |_ref_folder
         |_main.css
         |_ref_func.php
      |_checklog_folder
         |_clog.php
```

But when I use single dot, this work correctlyو While in all PHP training resources it is written that two dot should be used.

Why this happened and it works like this??

> **You can find ref_func.php in the directory tree in the third row
> from bottom to top**

I did not change any directory settings in PHP or Apache??

Comment: from which page are you trying to include the `ref_func.php` file? ie: where is it in the hierarchy shown?

Comment: Not compulsory and not related to the question but `require_once` is not a function, so you can (must?) use it [without brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21572508/14066311).

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I write tree of directory for this, if see in tree you can find ref_func.php in third row from down to top.

Comment: I can see the directory structure but what is NOT clear is which page you are loading into the browser that tries to `include` the `_ref_func.php` script

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius `require_once(../ref_func.php)` is in `clog.php` that is in folder with name `checklog_folder`.


and `ref_func.php` is in `ref_folder`

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. Looks like the answer below should work

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Your welcome, I wrote this before in the post.  below answer dosent work for me as I said.But I dont why...

Comment: Is it `_ref_folder` or `ref_folder` ? The same for file names - do they also have the leading underscore?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius It is ref_folder not _re_folder. first underline is for lines in tree of directory, not part of folder and file names.

Answer (score 2):

To understand simply:

- one dot (`.`) means the current directory (in which the script is);
- two dot (`..`) means `the parent directory`;
- `../../` means the parent directory of the parent directory;
- etc.

In your case, to import `ref_func.php` from `clog.php`, you need to:

- get out of `checklog_folder` (`../`)
- enter `ref_folder` (`../ref_folder/`)
- and access the `ref_func.php` (`../ref_folder/ref_func.php`)

So you will do:

```
require_once '../_ref_folder/_ref_func.php';
```

But I prefer

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../_ref_folder/_ref_func.php';
```

See why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35400764/14066311)

Comment: You're right.But as I wrote on my system instead of ../, work for me with ./ that I confused

Answer (score 1):

you should be doing this
`require_once("../_ref_folder/_ref_func.php");`
you forgot to write the folder in which ref_func.php file exist in your path.

Comment: I write tree of directory for this, if see in tree you can find ref_func.php in third row from down to top.